Issue with flutter_sound for recording purpose
I was tring to build and audio recorder app by using Flutter. For this purpose I tried to use flutter_sound. I read out this Documentation. For those example I build my own class:
import 'package:flutter_sound/flutter_sound.dart';
class MySoundRecorder extends FlutterSoundRecorder{
  MySoundRecorder _myRecorder = MySoundRecorder();
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    // Be careful : openAudioSession return a Future.
    // Do not access your FlutterSoundPlayer or FlutterSoundRecorder before the completion of the Future
    _myRecorder.openAudioSession().then((value) {
      setState(() {
        _mRecorderIsInited = true;
      });
    });
  }
  @override
  void dispose() {
    // Be careful : you must `close` the audio session when you have finished with it.
    _myRecorder.closeAudioSession();
    _myRecorder = null;
    super.dispose();
  }

  Future<void> record() async {
    await _myRecorder.startRecorder(
      toFile: _mPath,
      codec: Codec.aacADTS,
    );
  }
  Future<void> stopRecorder() async {
    await _myRecorder.stopRecorder();
  }
}

This througing an error that dispose() , openAudioSession() , closeAudioSession() are not in super class. Moreover that document used :
import 'package:flauto/flutter_sound.dart';

Which is no longer belong in pub.dev . How can I fixe this issue?
I searched on Internet. Used ChatGPT but none of them worked. I want to know what to do?
